# Probability distribution of the sum of products of discrete iid uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here is a problem I am working on, hoping to get some guidance from the experts here:

Given the arrays $C=[C_1,C_2,...,C_N]$ and $S=[S_1,S_2,...,S_N]$  of lengths $N$ with elements that are discrete iid uniform distributed with equal probability (p=1/2) of being $\pm$ 1

Consider the sum below:
\begin{equation*}
A=\sum_{l=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N C_lC_mC_n+S_lS_mC_n-C_lS_mS_n+S_lC_mS_n 
\end{equation*}
Let's assume $N$=16 (or higher). I'm trying to find the probability distribution/density of $A$ which is essentially the sum of $4N^3$ terms with each term being a triple product of discrete iid uniform rvs. It can be shown that these terms ($C_lC_mC_n, S_lS_mC_n, C_lS_mS_n, S_lC_mS_n$) are also uniform distibuted with p=1/2 for $\pm$1. Furthermore, it can be shown that they are uncorrelated (e.g. $E[(C_lC_mC_n)(S_lS_mC_n)]=0$ since they are zero mean ($E[C_i]=E[S_i]=0$) and $C_n^2=1$ ).

**Edit: As pointed out in comments below, the product terms are pairwise independent however they are not all jointly (mutually) independent. Therefore the question remains unsolved for now.**

So here are the questions:

1. What is the probability density/distribution of $A$? How can the pdf of $A$ be determined knowing that the product terms are identically distributed, zero mean, uncorrelated and pairwise independent but not jointly (mutually) independent?
2. If an exact solution is not tractable/feasible, are there any approximations that need to be used?
3. What is the variance of $A$? Since the product terms are uncorrelated and each has variance of 1, the variance of $A$ seems to simply be the sum of the variances of all the terms (i.e. the number of terms $4N^3$).
4. While the central limit theorem (CLT) applies for iid rvs, in this case the terms are uncorrelated, identically distributed and pairwise independent but not jointly (mutually) independent. Is there a special case of the CLT that can be applied here?

Comment: It seems $c_lc_mc_n$ and $s_ls_ms_n$ are also independent because $E[c_lc_mc_n\,s_ls_ms_n]=E[c_lc_mc_n]E[s_ls_ms_n]$ since $E[c_lc_mc_n]=E[s_ls_ms_n]=0$?

Comment: That's true but I'm not sure if that would help with the solution since the terms in the sum ($c_lc_mc_n, s_ls_mc_n, c_ls_ms_n, s_lc_ms_n$) haven't been shown to be independent.

Comment: they all have zero mean and correlation zero right?

Comment: ok I see what you're saying, the terms being independent really simplifies it and the CLT can be applied without any issues. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that first summand $(\sum C_i)^3$ etc ?  If so the limiting ditribtion is divide by $n^{-\frac 32} $ and get $C^3  _ S^2C $ with S,C independent normal.

Comment: This question still remains open because even though as Seyhmus has pointed out, the product terms ($C_lC_mC_n, S_lS_mC_n, C_lS_mS_n, S_lC_mS_n$) from the sum above are pairwise independent, they are not jointly (mutually) independent. That is the case for some rvs $X_i$ (i.e they are jointly independent) iff $E[\prod_{i=1}^nX_i]=\prod_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$. In the case above, $E[C_lC_mC_nS_lS_mC_nC_lS_mS_nS_lC_mS_n]$=1 since C_i^2=S_i^2=1 while the product of expectations is 0.

Comment: So based on the above, how can the pdf of $A$ be determined knowing that the product terms are identically distributed, zero mean, uncorrelated and pairwise independent but not jointly (mutually) independent?

Comment: Mike, thanks for the comment, I wasn't able to quite follow how it may help simplify the problem or help with a solution but please feel free to elaborate further or provide a reference.

Comment: Upon further study, turns out that $E(C_lC_mC_n S_lS_mC_n)=0=E(C_lC_mC_n)E(S_lS_mC_n)=0$ is not sufficient to show independence. See the "Note on Converse to Corollary" here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Condition_for_Independence_from_Product_of_Expectations

Comment: Well, turns out uncorrelated Bernoulli random variables are independent. The proof is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205597/how-to-show-that-these-random-variables-are-pairwise-independent

Comment: Also, it has been proven by Hong (1995) and others that if $X_1, X_2,...$ are jointly symmetric, pairwise independent and identically distributed with a finite second moment, then the central limit theorem holds for $X_1, X_2,...$. Reference: Hong, D.H., "A remark on the C.L.T. for sums of pairwise i.i.d. random variables," Math. Japon. 42, 87-89, 1995.