# How to show that these random variables are pairwise independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given the arrays $C=[C_1,C_2,...,C_N]$ and $S=[S_1,S_2,...,S_N]$  of lengths $N$ with elements that are discrete iid uniform distributed with equal probability (p=1/2) of being $\pm$ 1

Consider the random variables (for a given $l, n, m$):

$W=C_lC_mC_n$

$X=S_lS_mC_n$

$Y=C_lS_mS_n$

$Z=S_lC_mS_n$

It can be shown that these random variables ($W, X, Y, Z$) are zero mean, uniform distributed with equal probability (p=1/2) of being $\pm$ 1. Furthermore, it can be shown that they are uncorrelated (e.g. $E[WX]=E[(C_lC_mC_n)(S_lS_mC_n)]=0$ since they are zero mean ($E[C_i]=E[S_i]=0$) and $C_i^2=S_i^2=1$ ).

Now how can one go about showing that the random variables ($W, X, Y, Z$) are pairwise independent? (The expectation $E[WX]=E[(C_lC_mC_n)(S_lS_mC_n)]=0=E[W]E[X]=0$ but that doesn't necessarily mean they are independent). So I'm wondering what is a good way to show independence, any tricks one can use?

Comment: For Bernoulli variables, non-correlation implies independence.

Comment: More is true: any three random variables amongst W, X, Y and Z are independent (while (W,X,Y,Z) is not since, for example, WXYZ=+1 with probability 1).

Comment: Thanks did for sharing your further observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two Bernoulli variables  (with values in $\{0,1\}$) $X,Y$. We have

$$Cov(X,Y) = E(X,Y) - E(X) E(Y) = P(X=1,Y=1) - P(X=1) P(Y=1)$$

Then,  $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ implies $P(X=1,Y=1) = P(X=1) P(Y=1)$ which further implies $P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y)$. That is, for Bernoulli variables non-correlation implies independence.

Now, your $X,Y,Z,W$ are Bernoulli variables (except for a scaling-shifting that doesn't alter covariance/independence) pairwise uncorrelated, hence they are pairwise independent.

Comment: Thanks leonbloy, appreciate it! Nice to see such a simple proof using the {0,1} Bernoulli variables.